How to take derivatives of curves / surfaces and vector fields
In these lecture notes, in equation (2.4.14), we find the following claim. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, let $X$ and $Y$ be complete vector fields on $M$, let $\phi^-(-)$ and $\psi^-(-):$ $\mathbb{R} \times M \to M$ denote their flows, fix a point $p$ of $M$, and define
$$ \beta: \mathbb{R}^2 \to M, \ (s,t) \mapsto \phi^s \circ \psi^t \circ \phi^{-s} \circ \psi^{-t} (p).$$
Then the partial derivatives of $\beta$ are
$$ \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial s}(0,t) = X(p)-d\psi^t(\psi^{-t}(p))X(\psi^{-t}(p)),$$
$$ \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial t}(s,0) = d\phi^s(\phi^{-s}(p))Y(\phi^{-s}(p))-Y(p).$$
I can make sense of the equations, but I cannot understand why they should be true. Above all, I am puzzled by the minus sign: since I am differentiating a concatenation of maps, by the chain rule I would expect a concatenation of derivatives, not a sum or subtraction. My naive attempt would be
$$ \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial s}(0,t) = \left.\frac{d \phi^s}{ds}(\psi^t \circ \phi^{-s} \circ \psi^{-t}(p)) \circ \frac{d \psi^t}{dt}(\phi^{-s} \circ \psi^{-t}(p)) \circ \frac{d \phi^{-s}}{ds}(\psi^{-t}(p))\circ \frac{d }{dt}\psi^{-t}(p) \right\vert_{s=0} =$$
$$= X(p) \circ Y(p) \circ (-X(\psi^{-t}(p))) \circ (-Y(\psi^{-t}(p)))$$
but I do not even know what I am doing anymore, since I am starting to compose vectors, which does not make any sense... I think that I am missing some technique to take derivatives of curves / surfaces / vector fields / flows (this question might also be related, but I am not sure). Any help?

Let us rewrite
$$ \beta(s,t) = \phi (s,\psi (t,\phi (-s,\psi(-t,p)))).$$
Then note that
$$ p' := \psi (t,\phi (-0,\psi(-t,p))) = p, \quad p'' := \phi (-0,\psi(-t,p)) = \psi^{-t}(p).$$
Now using the chain rule multiple times and seeing everything as functions between Euclidean spaces we obtain
$$\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial s}(0,t) = \left(\frac{\partial \phi(s,p')}{\partial s}  \circ \frac{\partial s}{\partial s} + d\phi^s(p') \circ \frac{\partial (\psi (t,\phi (-s,\psi(-t,p))))}{\partial s} \right)  \vert_{(0,t)} = $$
$$ = X\circ \phi^0(p') \circ \mathrm{id} + d \phi^0(p')\circ\frac{\partial (\psi (t,\phi (-s,\psi(-t,p))))}{\partial s}\vert_{(0,t)} = $$
$$= X(p) + \frac{\partial (\psi (t,\phi (-s,\psi(-t,p))))}{\partial s}\vert_{(0,t)} \overset{\frac{\partial t}{\partial s} = 0}{=} X(p) + d\psi^t(p'') \circ \frac{\partial (\phi (-s,\psi(-t,p)))}{\partial s}\vert_{(0,t)} = $$
$$ = X(p) + d\psi^t(\psi^{-t}(p)) \circ \left(-X(\psi^{-t}(p)) + d\psi^{-t}(p) \circ \frac{\partial p}{\partial s} \right) \overset{\frac{\partial p}{\partial s} = 0}{=} X(p)-d\psi^t(\psi^{-t}(p))X(\psi^{-t}(p)),$$
as we wanted to show. A similar computation holds for the second equation.
